# map reduce problem, computation at values

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to map reduce paradigm, and trying to find better solution for the below problem.

I have a below set of rows - consisting google play store app reviews , the columns are AppName,Category,Type,rating, example row could be [Zomato,Food,Free,4.2],[Swiggy,Food,Paid,3.2] and so on
Question, find the ratio between average paid and free ratings for each category?
how can i solve this using map reduce paradigm / spark

is it like in map side emit key and composite value as (Food, (Free,4.2)), (Food,(Paid,3.2))
then do average computation at reduce side with list (values)? is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spark, that would be extremely simple. The map reduce logic would be completely hidden from you.

```scala
// let's define some data
val df = Seq((0, "cat_a", "free", 2.5), (1, "cat_a", "free", 3.5), (2, "cat_a", "paid", 4.1),
             (3, "cat_a", "paid", 4.5), (4, "cat_b", "free", 2.5), (5, "cat_b", "paid", 4.8))
    .toDF("app", "cat", "type", "rating")

df.show
+---+-----+----+------+
|app|  cat|type|rating|
+---+-----+----+------+
|  0|cat_a|free|   2.5|
|  1|cat_a|free|   3.5|
|  2|cat_a|paid|   4.1|
|  3|cat_a|paid|   4.5|
|  4|cat_b|free|   2.5|
|  5|cat_b|paid|   4.8|
+---+-----+----+------+
```

Then it's as simple as that:

```scala
val result = df.groupBy("cat").pivot("type")
    .agg(avg('rating))
    .withColumn("ratio", 'free / 'paid)

result.show
+-----+----+----+------------------+
|  cat|free|paid|             ratio|
+-----+----+----+------------------+
|cat_b| 2.5| 4.8|0.5208333333333334|
|cat_a| 3.0| 4.3|0.6976744186046512|
+-----+----+----+------------------+
```

NB: if you know that type can only be paid or free, you can use `.pivot("type", Seq("paid", "free")` which would be more efficient.